# What does ".*" means in backbone-rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have run `rails g backbone:scaffold Post title:string content:string` and it generates:

```
class Bbtst.Routers.PostsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @posts = new Bbtst.Collections.PostsCollection()
    @posts.reset options.posts

  routes:
    "new"      : "newPost"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"       : "index"
```

What does `".*"` do in last line? * means any symbols, but what is this dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Backbone.Router` behavior was changed since this generator has been written. And now it doesn't have sense because it match routes that contains zero or more dots (`#`, `#.`, ... , `#......`) .

I think original idea was to match any other routes and now you can do it using splat:

```
  ...
  routes:
    "new"      : "newPost"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    "*other"   : "index"
```

Comment: Seems like dots are parsed as you write. But it also somehow matches root (like /, /#, /#/). Any ideas why?

Comment: Yeah, it is because it matches zero or more dots

Comment: Oh, I see! It has been parsed like regexp ^\.*$ since there is no parameter name after *, but does not escapes * since it may be part of "*something". Thanks!